# JSF calendar select whole week

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, calendar, primefaces

is there a way to select the whole week from jsf calendar.
I know its possible to show the week of year in calendar, but i cant select that.

I use primefaces 3.2 with Apache MyFaces 2.0.

Best regards
Veote

Answer (score 3):

The Primefaces `p:calendar` component holds a value `java.util.Date` which is a point in time and no period.

But you can get the week of the year by converting the `Date` to a `Calendar`. Assuming your `p:calendar` value is stored in a backing bean variable `java.util.Date date`:

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
```

Then you will get the week of the year:

```java
cal.get( Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR )
```

Comment: I think its not exactly what I want. More interesting is the gui component. I want the user to select not a single data, but the week

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with the primefaces calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like this:

```
<p:calendar value="#{bean.dateArray}" mode="inline" selection="multiple"/>
```

In this situation dates will be passed to the JSF backing beans as a Date array.

Comment: I think that is also not what I want to have. I dont want the user to select more than one day. I only want the user to select a whole week and not a single day.

Comment: Create then a set of buttons (anchors), one for every week in calendar. 
When user clicks button linked with particular week, you will call a JavaScript function which will select all days from selected week. 

There is an example of how to select one day in calendar (JS function) at PrimeFaces demo website:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/calendarBasic.jsf